# What are the security implications to having cardano-wallet run on a public server?

Tags: wallet, api, mainnet

I want to use a public cardano-wallet server running on mainnet, so I can connect to it and create wallets for users of my iOS app.

1. How can I set up all transactions to be encrypted (over SSL) instead of over http?
2. Does the server keep logs of requests, and if so, how can I clear them? (I don't want to save a local record of anything I receive)
3. Are there any other security concerns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases, you should never manage users wallets with a hosted service. The whole point of a decentralized blockchain is that users are managing their own assets.

The best practice is to generate and keep the keys used in signing of a transaction within the iOS application managed by the user and use a hosted service to communicate with the Cardano blockchain (something like [blockfrost.io](https://blockfrost.io) or a hosted cardano-db-sync instance).

Comment: What if I'm using cardano-wallet to generate the pass-phrase and set a password - where does this get set? I can't use blockfrost to create a wallet, and I don't want to be responsible for the wallet either.

Comment: Your code needs to generate the passphrase, your application needs to protect the keys with a password. The user must be responsible for the wallet.